# How to arrange dimension order in multidimensional array for minimum run time?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

For example, I have a 3-by-4-by-5 array `m`.
If I have frequency manipulations like

```
m(:,:,rr) = a
```

Where should I place `rr` in the three position of the subscription?

In another word, which is faster below?

`m(rr,:,:) = a` where `m` is a 3-by-4-by-5 array

or

`m(:,:,rr) = a` where `m` is a 4-by-5-by-3 array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
n = 100000;
rr = randi(size(A,1), n, 1)

tic;
for k = 1:n
    A(rr(k),:,:) = k;
end
toc

tic;
for k = 1:n
    B(:,:,rr(k)) = k;
end
toc
```

I find the first method to be mildly slower:

```
Elapsed time is 0.078342 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.066406 seconds.
```

This makes sense to me because Matlab assigns matrices to memory as arrays going down the rows first (and then the columns, and then the 3rd, 4th 5th etc dimensions). This `A(:,:,k)` is a contiguous chunk of memory whereas `A(k,:,:)` is not.

Comment: Run and test it is a good way! B is 10 times faster than A on my computer!@Dan

Comment: @misssprite 10 times! What did you use for `A`, `B` and `n`? And what version of Matlab are you using? I use `A` and `B` as `m1` and `m2` in andrelucas' answer and I am running 2013a with 8 cores.

Comment: @Dan 2010b, and I used andrelucas' settings too, running on an old IBM server. I'm not sure about the detail cpu information, sort of 4 cores 16 threads.

Comment: @misssprite ok with taht older version of Matlab it's possible that they have since fixed this inefficiency with their JIT compiler. That might explain why you see such a dramatic improvement in comparison to my results. I guess it has become a less important consideration for those using the latest Matlab but something very important to consider for those using older versions.

Comment: @misssprite btw if the answer has solved your issue, you should consider [marking it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I'm newbie here. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The second way seems to be faster, at least where a and rr are constants.

```
m1 = rand (300,400,500);
m2 = rand (400,500,300);
a = 3;
rr = 7;

tic
m1(rr,:,:) = a; % 3-by-4-by-5 array
toc

tic
m2(:,:,rr) = a ; % 4-by-5-by-3 array 
toc


Elapsed time is 0.002322 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000174 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 but please add loops inside of your tic and toc. The overhead will likely make your single run test meaningless.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I just compiled it a few times to be sure.

Comment: that doesn't really do the same thing as loops though ;) what we should actually do is use the timeit function which was added in R2013b but is also on the file exchange.